# How to get to an item in a python enumerate()

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

I have two files, one that contains symbols (words) and another that is a map file.

Both files are text files. The map file does contain form feeds.

I want to find the line in the map file that is one above the line that contains
a symbol in the map file.

I have the following code.

```
Osymbolfile="alistofsymbols"
mapfile="amapfile"
maplines = (line.rstrip('\n\f') for line in open(mapfile))
for line in Osymbolfile:
    line = (line.rstrip('\n') )
    print "line= ",line
    linecount = 0
    for index, scanline in enumerate(maplines):
        if line in scanline:
            print "scanline=",scanline
            print "index=",index
        else:
            linecount = linecount + 1
    print "= ",linecount
```

After `print "index=",index` ,I've tried `print maplines[index-1]`, but I get an error.

How do I obtain the line above the `index`'th line in `maplines`?

Comment: Don't just say "I get an error". Show the error, with the traceback. Usually, it tells you _exactly_ what's wrong—and even if you can't understand it, the people who are trying to help you will, and can explain it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `maplines` object is a *generator expression*; these produce items on demand and are not indexable.

You could use a list comprehension instead:

```
maplines = [line.rstrip('\n\f') for line in open(mapfile)]
```

Now you have a indexable list object instead. Even better, you can now loop over this object multiple times; you cannot do that with a generator.

The proper way to handle your case however, is to store the *previous line* only:

```
with open(mapfile) as maplines:
    prev = None
    for line in maplines:
        if something in line:
            return prev
        prev = line
```

Comment: +1 for storing the previous line. A more general solution to this can be done with a `collections.deque`, which lets you specify a `maxlen` argument. The `deque` will then store up to the last `n` items, automatically deleting the oldest one when you add a new one. Then you can just use `prev[-x]` to get the `x`th item back.